# implementing work queue pattern with easynetq driver on rabbit mq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

How to implement work queue in rabbit mq using easynetq driver?

Also acknowledgement in both publisher and subscriber is desirable.

The idea is that one message will be processed only by a single subscriber. Is this a default behavior or the message fans out from the publisher to the subscriber?

Comment: Hi. This is a very broad question and sounds like you should go have a read of the (good) rabbitmq documentation.
Edit: Actually, if you are planning on using easynetq, they also have quite a lot of good documentation on how to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: It seems the default behavior for publish subscribe pattern is using direct exchange instead of fanout which i assumed. So only one consumer gets the message instead of multiple consumers getting the published message.

Comment: @TrustyCoder What exactly is your desired behavior? if you use the default pub/sub sample for easynetq you will have a usable worker queue setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple publish subscribe pattern implements the work queue pattern. When two consumers are present, the first consumers was getting all the messages because the prefetch count was 50 (default) preventing the other consumer from not getting any messages.